# Removing empty annotations from PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I wrote a `C#` program to remove annotations with no actions from PDF files. I use `iTextSharp`. However, in one of my files one non-empty annotation is removed (it's JavaScript action) while other non-empty aren't removed. Is it the case? Is it because of my code or is it faulty [PDF file](https://www.upload.ee/files/6679061/file.pdf.html)?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace removeEmpty
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            //Bytes will hold our final PDFs
            byte[] bytes;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (var reader = new PdfReader("sandri6.pdf")) {
                    using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
                            // get a page a PDF page
                            PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);
                            // get all the annotations of page i
                            PdfArray annotationsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

                            // if page does not have annotations
                            if (annotationsArray == null) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            // for each annotation
                            for (int j = 0; j < annotationsArray.Size; j++) {
                                // for current annotation
                                PdfDictionary currentAnnotation = annotationsArray.GetAsDict(j);

                                PdfDictionary annotationAction = currentAnnotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.AA);
                                if (annotationAction == null) {
                                    annotationsArray.Remove(j);
                                    Console.Write("Removed annotation {0} with no action from page {1}\n", j, i);
                                }
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }

                //grab the bytes before closing things out
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            //write thebytes to disk
            File.WriteAllBytes("output.pdf", bytes);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you provided contains 13 link annotations on its only page. And in contrast to your assumption (that all annotations have associated actions), the second one does not have an action and, therefore, is correctly removed by your code:

[image: Annotations screenshot]

As you see, the second annotation in object 778 has no **A** entry.

---

Thus, in case of your sample document, your code works correctly.

Please be aware, though, that some annotation types can not only have a standard action (**A** entry), they may also (or instead!) have additional actions in response to various trigger events. So, for a generic solution you also have to check for **AA** entries in annotations of those types.

---

There is an error in the code, though, even though it did not trigger in the sample document. In the annotation removal loop we see:

```
for (int j = 0; j < annotationsArray.Size; j++) {
    // for current annotation
    PdfDictionary currentAnnotation = annotationsArray.GetAsDict(j);

    PdfDictionary annotationAction = currentAnnotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
    if (annotationAction == null) {
        annotationsArray.Remove(j);
        Console.Write("Removed annotation {0} with no action from page {1}\n", j, i);
    }
}
```

Now let's assume we have a document with a page with two consecutive annotations without an action. Running the code against that document, only the first one will be removed, not the second, because `annotationsArray.Remove(j)` moves the annotation at `j+1` to position `j`, and then the loop variable is incremented, i.e. the annotation following the removed one is not tested at all!

You can fix this by either looping backwards, i.e.

```
for (int j = annotationsArray.Size - 1; j >= 0; j--)
```

or by decrementing `j` after a `annotationsArray.Remove(j)` call.

Looping backwards has the advantage that the `Console` output makes more sense, in the latter case the annotation index does not always represent the index in the original array, merely in the current intermediary array.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Does it mean that **AA** entry store JavaScript in the second annotation. I'm puzzled because in another [file](https://www.upload.ee/files/6680430/sandri6.pdf.html) where annotations are empty (Adobe Acrobat says so) they are not removed by the code. How do I fix this?

Comment: @menteith *"Does it mean that AA entry store JavaScript in the second annotation."* - No. As you see in the screenshot, the second annotation has neither an **A** nor an **AA** entry.

Comment: @menteith Concerning your other file: I cannot reproduce your observation. Exactly those annotations without action (which happen to be the link annotations around the author names) are removed. And I checked both by inspecting the PDF objects and by clicking around in Acrobat.

Comment: That's weird, because I doubled checked and these annotations have not been removed in my case. Which version of iTextSharp do you use? I use latest – 5.5.10 and compile the code using VS 2015. [Here](https://www.upload.ee/files/6680677/output.pdf.html) is the output file with actions that have not been removed. I also updated my first post to show all the code. Would you be so kind to examine this?

Comment: @menteith You changed your code and don't check for **A** anymore, only for **AA**. I used your original code which checked again **A**. (When I mentioned **AA** I did not mean you have look for it *instead of* looking for **A** but *in addition to* looking for **A**). But now an actual error even in your original code becomes clear. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I am deeply thankful for your explanations. I will knuckle down on your solution to get a better understanding of it. I'm new to C# and I'd like to learn this language. I have already accepted and upvoted your answer but you would help me a lot  if you could have a look at my code after a few days. Thanks to you I have a working code to remove empty annotations ,and I have another piece of code (working) to change annotations. I'd like to combine these two pieces of code as as a way of advancing my C# skills. Once again – I really appreciate your explanations!